# How to host app in different port in docker and python

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, server

I have a web project which I have hosted on the server. Frontend is angular, backend is flask and database is mongodb and all are made as a docker container linking with each other.

I am doing flowing steps

1. Backend Hosting

Backend is created as a docker container at 10.31.61.52.

Use “docker build . -t backend” to create docker image.And

after it is build use - “ docker run -itd -p 5000:5000 --linkmongodb:mongodb --name skybridge_backend backend” to run this container.Your backend is good to go!

2 Frontends Hosting
Frontend is created as a docker container at 10.31.61.52
docker build . -t frontend” to create docker image.And

after it is build use - “ docker run -itd -p 80:9000 --linkskybridge_backend:skybridge_backend --name skybridge_frontend frontend” torun this container

instead of 80 want to use 8080 as host port so that my URL would be below.

Then just want to access the URL like this http://10.31.61.52:8080/login

Answer (score 0):

You specify the port redirection from the host machine to the container using `docker run -p <host port>:<container port>`. Therefore changing the port from 80 to 8080 in the command to run the frontend container like this should do the trick:

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:9000 --linkskybridge_backend:skybridge_backend --name skybridge_frontend frontend
```

Answer (score 0):

when i run this command docker run -itd -p 80:9000 --linkskybridge_backend:skybridge_backend --name skybridge_frontend frontend

linking is happening but internally its referring port 80 in the url http://10.31.61.52/login and page is displaying

but want to change it to port 8080 so that my URL should be http://10.31.61.52:8080/login..
when i try to access this url page not opening.

http://10.31.61.52/login -- Login screen come up
http://10.31.61.52:8080/login -- Login screen not coming

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [
       {
          "TOTAL_USAGE":17243,
          "MNTH":"NOV",
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc"
       },
       {
          "MNTH":"AUG",
          "TOTAL_USAGE":1104,
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc"
       },
       {
          "MNTH":"OCT",
          "TOTAL_USAGE":45,
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc"
       },
       {
          "MNTH":"JUL",
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc",
          "TOTAL_USAGE":19747
       },
       {
          "TOTAL_USAGE":1539,
          "SERVICE_NAME":'CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc',
          "MNTH":"SEP"
       }
    ];
```

Comment: Can You some help me sort it in Javascripts and ES6

Comment: Basically It Should sort Month wise [{ 
          "MNTH":"JUL",
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc",
          "TOTAL_USAGE":19747
       }, {
          "MNTH":"AUG",
          "TOTAL_USAGE":1104,
          "SERVICE_NAME":"CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc"
       }, {
          "TOTAL_USAGE":1539,
          "SERVICE_NAME":'CustomerConsumerEmcsfdc',
          "MNTH":"SEP"
       }]

Comment: Can you give context to the answer?